How can I let a shared library, called by Python, access the same Python instance's globals?
So I've created this main.py:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import ctypes


foo = 1


# Should print 2, but prints 1
def print_foo():
    global foo
    print(foo)


def main():
    global foo
    foo = 2

    dll = ctypes.PyDLL("./foo.so")

    foo = dll.foo
    foo.restype = None
    foo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

and this foo.c:
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <assert.h>

#define CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR() {\
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {\
        PyErr_Print();\
        fprintf(stderr, "Error detected in foo.c:%d\n", __LINE__);\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }\
}

void foo(void) {
    PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("main");
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(module);

    PyObject *print_foo = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "print_foo");
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(print_foo);

    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(print_foo, NULL);
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(result);
}

I've compiled foo.c to foo.so with gcc foo.c -o foo.so -shared -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wfatal-errors -g -lpython3.13 -I/home/trez/.pyenv/versions/3.13.0/include/python3.13 -L/home/trez/.pyenv/versions/3.13.0/lib -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/trez/.pyenv/versions/3.13.0/lib -lm, where those last flags came from running python3.13-config --includes --ldflags.
Running python3.13 main.py prints 1. It implies that the foo = 2 statement did not happen in the instance which printed foo, which is bad.
The reason this program currently prints 1, is because the PyImport_ImportModule() (docs) call essentially creates a new environment, rather than reusing the original one.
Changing it to PyImport_AddModule() (docs) or PyImport_AddModuleRef() (docs) prints this:
AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'print_foo'
Error detected in foo.c:20

If we look at PyImport_AddModule its docs, we just see:

Similar to PyImport_AddModuleRef(), but return a borrowed reference.

And if we then look at PyImport_AddModuleRef its docs, there's this snippet:

This function does not load or import the module; if the module wasn’t already loaded, you will get an empty module object. Use PyImport_ImportModule() or one of its variants to import a module.

So this seems to imply that the AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'print_foo' error was caused by the module not being loaded. This doesn't make sense to me though, since using PyImport_AddModule/PyImport_AddModuleRef and adding this after the assert(module); line:
PyObject *g = PyEval_GetGlobals();
CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
PyObject *g_repr = PyObject_Repr(g);
CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
const char *s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(g_repr);
CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
printf("s: '%s'\n", s);

prints this:
s: '{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x6ffc309a5e00>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/home/trez/Programming/ctypes-run-bug/main.py', '__cached__': None, 'ctypes': <module 'ctypes' from '/home/trez/.pyenv/versions/3.13.0/lib/python3.13/ctypes/__init__.py'>, 'foo': <_FuncPtr object at 0x6ffc30946450>, 'print_foo': <function print_foo at 0x6ffc308231a0>, 'main': <function main at 0x6ffc3088f4c0>}'
AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'print_foo'
Error detected in foo.c:28

Note the 'print_foo': <function print_foo at 0x6ffc308231a0> near the end of the first line, implying that the function is found.
My guess as to what's happening here is that these globals are from the original Python instance, but that the PyImport_AddModule("main") call somehow fails to find that instance.
How do I keep main.py untouched, while modifying foo.c in a way that 2 gets printed, instead of 1? Cheers.

Have you tried just accessing the entry point from sys.modules? It should've in the key "__main__".  There must be a way to access that from the C api

Note, Python doesn't really have interpreter -level globals, each module namespace acts is a global namespace. It would be more complicated if you mean "access the globals of the module calling out to the shared.library", but using sys.modules might be the solution in that case as well

@juanpa.arrivillaga It would be more complicated if you mean "access the globals of the module calling out to the shared.library" - this is exactly what I'm looking for. Running import sys foo = 1 def main(): \tfoo = 2 \tprint(vars(sys.modules["__main__"])) if __name__ == "__main__": main() prints a dict containing 'foo': 1, instead of 'foo': 2 :/

well, of course, because foo = 2 is assigning to a local variable.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for catching that! I'm working on figuring out how to translate sys.modules["__main__"] to Python's C API right now, and I'll post it as an answer and credit you once I have it (assuming it fully works)

Yeah, but note, that isn't the module where the call to the shared library happens, necessarily. For that, the easiest (albeit clunky) solution  is to pass either the name of the module at the same time on the python side, (easy at least with foo(__name__)) or the module object itself (foo(sys.modules[__name__])

@juanpa.arrivillaga I unfortunately don't want to have the Python caller need to pass their name, so that won't work. I'm trying what you suggested before, and I've gotten it down to having foo() only contain the one-liner PyObject_CallObject(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyDict_GetItemString(PyDict_GetItemString(PyModule_GetDict(PyDict_GetItemString(PyEval_GetGlobals(), "sys")), "modules"), "__main__"), "print_foo"), NULL);, but for some reason it causes the print(foo) to print <_FuncPtr object at 0x7af3e4d46450>. Any clue?

Have you tried any of these? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html#system-functions so maybe PySys_GetObject("modules") which will be a python dict

@juanpa.arrivillaga I had not, thanks. It condenses what I had down to PyObject_CallObject(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyDict_GetItemString(PySys_GetObject("modules"), "__main__"), "print_foo"), NULL);, but the print(foo) still prints <_FuncPtr object at 0x7e303125e450>. Ideally there'd of course be a caller-agnostic solution, rather than hardcoding the assumption that the caller came from the __main__ module, though maybe there'd be some way to query the name of the caller's module automatically.

Importing a module doesn’t run if '__name__' == '__main__': so print_foo() would be expected to print 1.  If main() were called, foo is reassigned to dll.foo so I’d expect <_FuncPtr object at …> to be printed.

What were you expecting from print(foo)? You mean foo()?

juanpa.arrivillaga gave the great advice to have the C code get the main module by inspecting the C equivalent of sys.modules, and this solution does successfully print 2:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import ctypes


foo = 1


def print_foo():
    global foo
    print(foo)


def main():
    global foo
    foo = 2

    dll = ctypes.PyDLL("./foo.so")

    bar = dll.bar
    bar.restype = None
    bar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <assert.h>

#define CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR() {\
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {\
        PyErr_Print();\
        fprintf(stderr, "Error detected in foo.c:%d\n", __LINE__);\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }\
}

void bar(void) {
    PyObject *modules = PySys_GetObject("modules");
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(modules);

    PyObject *main_object = PyDict_GetItemString(modules, "__main__");
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(main_object);

    PyObject *print_foo = PyObject_GetAttrString(main_object, "print_foo");
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(print_foo);

    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(print_foo, NULL);
    CHECK_PYTHON_ERROR();
    assert(result);
}

MarkTolonen made me aware that I was accidentally overwriting my foo value of 2 with my foo = dll.foo line. I've changed that to bar = dll.bar; bar.restype = None; bar(), and renamed void foo(void) { ... } to void bar(void) { ... }.
As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned though, if print_foo() and foo = 1 are moved to say helper.py, and I change main() to look like def main(): helper.baz() (where baz() looks like the old main()), then I get AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'print_foo'. This is fine in my case, since I don't mind hardcoding the module name where print_foo() resides in foo.c.

so maybe you could wrap your function in a python function that will pass the current module as an argument without the user having to do anything.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Definitely, though for my niche use-case it didn't end up being necessary; feel free to check https://github.com/MyNameIsTrez/grug-terminal-game-python to see what you helped out finishing :)
